# Livecycle Designer - Table row overlap issue

Tags: acrobat, livecycle, dynamic-forms, livecycle-designer, xfa

I been looking all around for a solution to my issue but i can't find a fix yet. Here's my problem:

I have a dynamic PDF which contains a table and several text fields per row that grow vertically as the user adds text (multiple lines  and expand to fit vertically). The table properly breaks when the content doesn't fit in the current page, however, I found out that in some scenarios, with a certain amount of characters, the row sometimes overlaps the content in the next page (See below).

[image]

By by adding more text to the offending line, the content in that row properly breaks to the next page (See below)

[image]

I am not sure whether or not this is a known issue with the tool or I am missing some sort of configuration/setting in the template. I haven't found anything online or in the Adobe Documentation. Any thoughts?

I am using:

- **Adobe Acrobat Pro 9**
- **Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 8.2**
- The **form version** of the PDF runs in **Adobe Reader 7.0.5** (For compatibility purposes with one of the tools our clients are using)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time looking for a solution, I found a single blog of someone who had the same issue, which by the way Adobe was kind enough to not document it... Anyhow, the following two processing instructions need to be added to the XML

```
<?layout allowDissonantSplits 1?>
<?layout allowJaggedRowSplits 1?>
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<template xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.4/">
   <?formServer defaultPDFRenderFormat acrobat7.0.5dynamic?>
   <?formServer allowRenderCaching 0?>
   <?formServer formModel both?>
   <?layout allowDissonantSplits 1?>
   <?layout allowJaggedRowSplits 1?>
```

The author specifies that the directives should only be added if this problem occurs. I wonder why these instructions should only be used in this situation. The full blog post can be found here:

http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2011/10/10/lc-forms-es-text-overlapping-on-page-break-using-nested-subforms/

Hope this saves time to someone else